# I'm sorting a map but the original map does not get affected

Tags: java

I'm trying to sort a map in a method. But the original map does not get sorted. I know I'm creating a new instance of a map and assigning the original map to the new map instance and sorting it. But how do I sort the original map here

```
private void sortData(Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> resultData) {
    System.out.println("result data before sort : "+resultData);
    Map<String, List<String>> sortedData =  new TreeMap(Collections.reverseOrder());
    for(Map.Entry<String, Map<String, List<String>>> modEntry : resultData.entrySet()) {
        sortedData.putAll(modEntry.getValue());
        System.out.println("Sorted : "+sortedData);
        for (Iterator<Entry<String, List<String>>> iterator = sortedData.entrySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Entry<String, List<String>> entry = (Entry<String, List<String>>)iterator.next();
            List<String> stats = (List<String>)entry.getValue();
            Collections.sort(stats, new Comparator<String>() {
                DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                @Override
                public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                    try {
                        return f.parse(o2).compareTo(f.parse(o1));
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    System.out.println("result date after sort : "+resultData);
}
```

Here my original map is 'resultData'. I'm reverse sorting the Value of the 'resultData' by key by creating a new instance of a treemap. After sorting the original data is still unsorted. I know that I'm sorting a different map and expecting a different map to be sorted but how do I get the original map sorted?

Comment: Why not just return the sorted data and use that?

Comment: My sorted data is a Map within the original Map. I want to return the original map. If I have to return the sorted data then I have to go through another loop to assign

Comment: `resultData = sortedData;`?

Comment: I'm trying to sort the inner Map and also the list inside the inner Map

Comment: Just as a design note, in Java, if you've got some data with more than two layers of generics, it's probably time to start define some classes.  `Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>` is probably too complicated to keep track of.

Answer (score 0):

I added resultData.put(modEntry.getKey(), sortedData); in the outer for loop and it fixed the issue.